# How can I compute the closeness of several books in this method?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linear-algebra

Have you ever seen how Netflix recommends you certain movies based on the movies you have previously seen and enjoyed watching? I am trying to do the same thing but for a set of books.

I have 53 books and 32 users. The 32 users have rated each of the books on a scale from 5 to -5 with 5 being I loved it. The formula which is used to compute how "similar" two books are compared to each other is as follows:

[image: Similarity function]

`x1*y1` represents user one's rating of book x and book y, `x2*y2` represents the 2nd user's rating on the same 2 books, continuing for all users.

The array being passed into this method is the main array. Each of the elements of the main array corresponds to a user, and each of the elements in the user arrays correspond to a book. (32 user arrays, each of which is itself a 53-element array)

The arrays which hold each user's rating are in order,  with `compValuehold[0][0]` representing the first user's rating to the first book, `compValuehold[0][2]` representing the first user's rating to the second book, etc.

```
 public static void DisplayRatings(double[][] compValuehold)
        {

            double eachUserProduct = 0;
            double denominatorXSum = 0;
            double denominatorYSum = 0;
            double Score = 0;
            int counterForScore = 0;
            double[] calculatedValues = new double[52];



            //this for loop should calculate each book's ratings and store it
            //in an array
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                {
                    eachUserProduct += compValuehold[j][i] * compValuehold[j][i + 1];
                    denominatorXSum += compValuehold[j][i] * compValuehold[j][i];
                    denominatorYSum += compValuehold[j][i + 1] * compValuehold[j][i + 1];

                }

                denominatorXSum = Math.Sqrt(denominatorXSum);
                denominatorYSum = Math.Sqrt(denominatorYSum);
                Score = eachUserProduct / (denominatorXSum * denominatorYSum);
                calculatedValues[counterForScore] = Score;
                counterForScore += 1;
                denominatorXSum = 0;
                denominatorYSum = 0;
                eachUserProduct = 0;

            }

        }
```

I am able to write code to compare the very first book to the rest of the books. **My problem is that I need to find out for EACH book which book is the most similar. Which means computing that formula a lot of times.** I don't know how to do this for all the books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you're doing is determining the [Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) of "book vectors", where each vector is composed of each user's ratings for a particular book.

Trying to do this all in one function is likely to give you a headache with debugging;
I'd recommend breaking your problem up into more manageable pieces:

- Write a function that creates a book vector for a particular book.

  - In your case, this would be pulling a given column from your `compValuehold` matrix
- Write a function that computes the similarity between two book vectors.
- Loop over all pairs of books, calculating the similarity for each pair.

  - (Note that `similarity(a, b) == similarity(b, a)`)

This approach also makes it much easier to change your similarity function if somewhere down the road you come up with a better way of comparing books.

Here's an example implementation of the first two sub-problems (keep in mind that they aren't particularly efficient):

```
static int[] GetBookVector(int[][] ratingMatrix, int bookIndex)
{
    int[] book = new int[ratingMatrix.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ratingMatrix.Length; i++)
    {
        book[i] = ratingMatrix[i][bookIndex];
    }

    return book;
}

static double Similarity(int[] v1, int[] v2)
{
    if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Vectors must be of the same length.");
    }

    int numerator = 0;
    double v1Norm = 0;
    double v2Norm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
    {
        numerator += v1[i] * v2[i];
        v1Norm += v1[i] * v1[i];
        v2Norm += v2[i] * v2[i]; 
    }

    v1Norm = Math.Sqrt(v1Norm);
    v2Norm = Math.Sqrt(v2Norm);

    return (numerator / (v1Norm * v2Norm));
}
```

Comment: Yes. @dckrooney. This is right. Cosine similarity. I am having difficulty with the for loops..I almost have this but I need to get the for loops proper and perhaps introduce another jagged array but the implementation of what is in my head is headaching..

Comment: Can you please suggest what changes in terms of code I should make to make it work out? I think I need another for loop somehwhere and another jagged array.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to write this code. I got it working before I saw your code and what I did was use 3 for loops with a jagged array. Your solution is probably more understandable because of its organized breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

As @dckrooney pointed out, you are computing the cosine similarity between two vectors, each vector representing the "rating profile" for all your users. Writing that function from scratch is fine, but you might consider using a Linear Algebra library for this, which will simplify your work. For instance, using a library like Math.NET, you would represent your array as a Matrix, say Ratings, and you can then extract the Columns and perform your computations in a more straightforward manner, along these lines:

```
public double Similarity(DenseMatrix matrix, int col1, int col2)
{
    var column1 = matrix.Column(col1);
    var column2 = matrix.Column(col2);
    var similarity = column1.DotProduct(column2) / (column1.Norm(2)+column2.Norm(2));
    return similarity;
}
```

You might get some slight performance benefit from working off a raw array, but arguably, the code is much more readable and easy to maintain that way. Furthermore, Math.NET allows you to use [native providers](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/2013/2/3/mathnet-numerics-with-native-linear-algebra.html) and run your computations using linear algebra directly on your CPU, which can get you a nice performance boost.

Beyond that, yes you have to repeat that computation for every column, which can become quite expensive, especially if you have a large matrix. One way around this is to use Singular Value Decomposition, which can help you reduce the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an error?

```
    denominatorYSum += compValuehold[j][i + 1] * compValuehold[j][i + 1];
..
...
..
denominatorYSum = Math.Sqrt(denominatorYSum);
```

If it's not, just change the code to

```
denominatorYSum += compValuehold[j][i + 1];
```

Sqrt is very expensive, it's essentially a loop.

Assuming the above is an error, I would just get rid of both Sqrt calculations completely. Or move it to this line,

```
Score = eachUserProduct / Math.Sqrt(denominatorXSum * denominatorYSum);
```

Math.Sqrt(25) * Math.Sqrt(25) is 25. Math.Sqrt(25*25) is 25. Additionally, higher value with have higher square roots. So you could get rid of the Math.Sqrt() calls entirely and the calculations will still be the same as far as distance ordering(similarity).

This is more of a math problem than a programming one . . . I hope I didn't do your homework.

Comment: Hi @justinDanielson, the line isn't an error. The i+1 represents the next book we compare to. The y is suppose to be the next book. Also, in the formula that I was given it says add up all the x^2s and add up all the y^2s in denominator and square root each X sum and Y sum and then multiply. That is what the formula looks like. See the denominator of the formula? My code denominatorXSum adds the denominator's X^2 terms and then decominatorYSum adds all the Y^2 terms, then outside the for loop it square roots the sums and THEN multiplies them. My code can only compare book 1 to the rest.

Comment: What I am trying to do is for EVERY book, do the same thing my code does for the first book..My code above only finds what book is the most similar to the first book in the array...I must do that for every book somehow to find out what EVERY book is similar to...the counterpart of every book in terms of similarity.

Comment: On second thought I give up...I have been at it for 5 hours and the logic is giving me headaches so screw this.

Comment: If you need to do it for every book, just wrap everything into another loop. I thought that was obvious, I was merely making suggestions to optimize the current processing since that will be needed.

Comment: I'm saying the get rid of the Math.Sqrt because you're doing Math.Sqrt(y*y) ... that makes no sense. The Sqrt of y^2 is y.. don't waste the function call doing Sqrt(y^2)